# Unable to Ping communicate internal IP in azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu-14.04, azure-virtual-network

I am creating a VM in azure (Ubuntu 14.04) in East US 2 region with internal ip address say 10.199.43.143

I am creating another ubuntu VM in East US 2 region (same Region) which is given an internal ip address say 10.199.54.131

I am not able to communicate/ping/http between these two VMs even though the firewall in ubuntu is off using the internal IP.

Can two VMs in same region communicate via internal ips in AZURE ? without creating a VPN ?

Comment: Yes, if they are on the same VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both VMs are in the same virtual network. Before creating Virtual Machines, you have to setup a Virtual Network. That way you make sure all machines can communicate with each other. Also make sure you are creating new VMs using "From Gallery" instead of "Quick Create", that is the only way you will see options to select the virtual network (which you have to create prior to vm creation)

**Virtual Network Overview**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156007.aspx